# how to display the current year in my maste page

Tags: master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I have the folloiwng footer, inside my custom master page:-

```
<div id="customFooter"  class="noindex">&copy; .. Group 2013</div>
```

but is there a way to dynamically access the current year , instead of manually typing the year .(I am trying to avoid using javaScript to implement this)?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid javascript? It would be a fairly simple bit of javascript, and it's already a requirement for SP.

Answer (score 2):

somthing on the lines of:

```
<div>
     <label id="datetime" runat="server"><%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %></label>
</div>
```

that should do it ;)

so that would be for you:

```
<div id="customFooter"  class="noindex">&copy; .. Group <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %></div>
```

personally that above i would do it within the layouts page ratha than the masterpage!

if you need to have it in the masterpage an run into that error

> "Code blocks are not allowed in this file"

than use the following code within your web.config, it will allow code to be entered into the masterpage!

```
<PageParserPaths> 
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/_catalogs/masterpage/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" /> 
</PageParserPaths>
```

the above code might hit performance issues if you reach beyond 15 aspx pages within the specified virtual path and is noted here:

**Using PageParserPath directive can cause performance problems**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659203

**EDIT**

if performance is going to be an issue than your going to have to think about editing the masterpage to suit your needs ;) by that i mean have a placeholder at the bottom where you want the date to appear, now withing your layouts file (aspx) that is connected to the masterpage, add the placeholder at the bottom and then add the div code, should work like a charm!

Comment: thanks but adding this code ave raised the following exception . "Sorry, something went wrong 
An error occurred during the processing of /discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom.master. Code blocks are not allowed in this file. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: d94f499c-4842-f084-3eee-ffef56002600 

Date and Time: 10/4/2013 10:33:39 AM "

Comment: just edited answer

Comment: so i will have performance issues if i use PageParsePath ?. so i will keep the year hard coded !!!

Comment: it depends on what file location "virtual path" your using! yours will be masterpage (where its stored) on sharepoint within the catalogs (siteaction-sitesettings-masterpage and layouts), you need to count how many aspx files you have there! the link i posted shows how to get around it by increasing the number from 15 to say 50!, there is nothing wrong with having it dynamic! you can try it out and see the result weather it hinders on performance which i dout!

Comment: just ammended my answer and should realy be the way to go about it! recap: masterpage add new placeholder, in layouts file add new placeholder and the div, save and reload!